# Trying to move an object down every second with thread sleep method but it keeps making my object dissapear

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program that moves an object (I used a radio button in this code as a place holder) down to the bottom of the form. I use a loop that doesn't end until the radio buttons location reaches the bottom of the form. I want to make the object move at a speed that I can see it so I use the thread.sleep method to stall the loop for a second before it starts again. I keep running into the problem that when I use the sleep method it makes my object disappear instead of moving. I am open for any suggestion on how to implement this better and why this is happening. Just started using forms after console so I am very unexperienced in forms. 
Thank you in advance for any advice :)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Visible = false;
        MoveButton();
    }
    public void MoveButton()
    {
        int BoundaryY = this.ClientSize.Height;
        while (radioButton1.Location.Y < BoundaryY)
        {
           radioButton1.Location = new Point(radioButton1.Location.X, radioButton1.Location.Y+1);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your loop is blocking the form from refreshing itself. Try using a timer instead.

Comment: The UI thread is responsible for reacting to user input. It cannot process user input when it is sleeping, so calling Sleep on the UI thread is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `Thread.Sleep` blocks the thread of your form and the while loop doesn't give any chance to the form to redrew itself. You need to use a timer.

This is an example on how to implement it

```
// At the form global level.
System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();

button1.Visible = false;
t.Elapsed += tElapsed;
t.Interval = 1000;
t.SynchronizingObject = this;
t.Start();    



public void tElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    int BoundaryY = this.ClientSize.Height;
    // Adding the radiobutton Height to the BoundarY value keeps the radiobutton visible
    if(radioButton1.Location.Y <= (BoundaryY - b.Height))
        radioButton1.Location = new Point(radioButton1.Location.X, radioButton1.Location.Y+1);
}
```

However you need to declare your timer as a form level variable to avoid a local variable that will be out of scope at the end of the click event

In this example I have used a `System.Timers.Timer` but there are other Timer classes available in the NET Framework and probably, given the context, you could use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer that is less problematic to work with UI controls. A good article about NET Timers is the following [Comparing the Timers classes in the Net Framework Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

Comment: Wouldn't a WinForm's timer be more appropriate for a beginner?

Comment: @LarsTech, yes of course. But looking at the OP willingness to work with threads... right a warning about UI threads should be added here

Comment: @Steve - The timer could be declared locally as the reference to the `tElapsed` method will prevent it being garbage collected.

Comment: @Steve - Also you need to invoke the updates to the UI onto the UI thread.

Comment: @Enigmativity SynchronizeObject takes care of your last comment

Comment: @Enigmativity about the first comment. I am not very confortable with this kind of behavior. I prefer to have it as a form level variable but that's not a big deal

Comment: @Steve - Sweet - I hadn't seen `SynchronizingObject` before.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to move the loop into a separate thread that marshalls moving the button back to the UI thread.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Visible = false;

    ThreadStart start = new ThreadStart(Animate);
    Thread thread = new Thread(start);
    thread.Start();
}

public void MoveButton(int x, int y)
{
    radioButton1.Location = new Point(x, y);
}

public void Animate()
{
    int BoundaryY = this.ClientSize.Height;
    while (radioButton1.Location.Y < BoundaryY)
    {
        if (radioButton1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            radioButton1.Invoke(new Action<int, int>(MoveButton), radioButton1.Location.X, radioButton1.Location.Y + 1);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Code will loop for the specified Interval Per case. 
When it Reaches case 5, It will loop back to case 1. 
To stop the timer on case 5, I put this.Close(); which is for my form to close and stop the timer when it reaches case 5.
You can choose what you want for each case.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.IO;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public static int Countername1; //Calls Countername1 = 0;

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                Countername1 = 0;
            }

            private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    Countername1++;
                    switch (Countername1)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            //You can put whatever code
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            //You can put whatever code
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            //You can put whatever code
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            //You can put whatever code
                            break;

                        case 5:
                            this.Close(); //You can put whatever code
                            timer1.Stop(); //You can put whatever code
                            break;
                    }
                    if (Countername1 == 5) //Loops from Case 1 to Case 5
                    {
                        Countername1 = 0;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: will you please describe what new you have done here? it would be great if you add some explanation for future visitors